# How do I figure how much is consumed from a pie?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was trying to create some interesting word problems. I started off with questions like "if A takes away ax proportion of a pie, b then takes away bx proportion of what is left of the pie, C takes away cx portion of what is left of pie, how much is left?" So for example, if x was 1/5, a was 3, b was 1, and c was 5, A would take 3/5 of the pie, B would take 1/5 of what was left, and C would take 5/5 of what was left, or the remainder of the pie.

I then started tinkering with the reverse. Instead of wondering what was the amount left, I tried to figure out what x would have to be in order for a certain amount of pie left given constants of a, b, and c.

Since I was having fun playing with the numbers, I then wondered, ok instead of 3, what about 4, 5, 6, or 7? And then I sort of hit a bit of a roadblock. I asked myself, what if A takes ax part of the pie, B takes bx of what is left, C takes cx of what is left, D, E, and F take the same absolute amount as c, and then G takes gx of what is left? So to start with, I made a=b=c=7, g=8, and tried to make sure the pie was 1/7 of the original.

I didn't know how to approach this problem, so I entered into an equation solver the input of (1/7)=(7x)(7x)(7x)(dx)(ex)(fx)(8x) and then started to play around with the numbers until D, E, and F take as much as C does. This won't give an exact solution, but I wanted to play around with the numbers a bit. Soon however I ran into something which made me believe I was approaching this in a flawed way.

I entered into the solver (1/7)=(7x)(7x)(7x)(11x)(30x)(91x)(8x) and an approximate numerical solution was x=0.05603033. The problem was when I tried to do a sanity check.

So A takes away 7x of the pie. So A takes 0.05603033*7= 0.39221231.

B then takes away 7x of what is remaining after A took away this amount. So B takes away (1-0.05603033*7)*0.05603033*7 = 0.2383818

C then takes away (1-0.05603033*7)(1-0.05603033*7)*0.05603033*7 = 0.1447951

I had guessed d=11 to try to make C and D take the same ammount. D would then take away (1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*7)*0.05603033*11= 0.1383794

I had guessed e= 30 to make C and E take the same amount. E would then take away (1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*11)*0.05603033*30= 0.1447951

I had guessed f= 91 to make C and F take the same amount. F would then take away (1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*11)*(1-0.05603033*30)*0.05603033*131 = -0.4305202

G then takes away (1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*7)*(1-0.05603033*11)*(1-0.05603033*30)*(1-0.05603033*131)*0.05603033*8= 0.2051798

And then I realized I had a problem. I knew that randomly guessing proportions that D, E, and F would take would not lead to exact answers, but negative numbers should not appear. For example, this would lead to the calculation that A, B, C, D, and E ate more than the entire pie, so F takes away a negative proportion. This doesn't make any sense. It is clear I am approaching this thoguht experiment from the wrong direction, but I don't know where I went wrong.

Sorry if formatting or tagging is bad, I don't really know how this site works differently than other question sites.

Comment: It is a very rambling post. Leaving your thought experiments  aside, can you clearly write the exact problem you want to solve ?

Comment: The underlying principle is that if (for example) $~0 < ax,bx < 1,~$ and $~ax~$ is removed, then what is left is $~(1 - ax).~$  Then if $~bx~$ is removed from what remains, then what is left is $~(1 - ax) \times (1 - bx).$

Comment: @trueblueanil 3rd paragraph

Answer (score 0):

I think you can formulate this by saying that no pie will be left after all take a chunk. Taking a chunk n/x of a reminder R makes it R * n/x. So... this is with different number of people:

0 = 1 - a/x

0 = (1 - a/x) * (1 - b/x)

0 = (1 - a/x) * (1 - b/x) * (1 - c/x)

Well, you see the pattern. And to solve this, any of the factors (the content inside a parenthesis) just has to be 0. In your case, though, the last one. And that is how you find x given the letters: just make it equal to the last letter.

Comment: I wasn't trying to make none of the pie left, that was an example I gave with c taking away 5/5 of what was left. I wanted to figure out how to figure out the ammounts when the ammount of pie left is an arbitrary number between 0 and 1.